# Add a TITLE and DESCRIPTION attribute to an SVG in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

Pretty much as the title states.

I wish to add the TITLE and DESCRIPTION in the SVG file for accessibility purposes.

I'm aware that you can edit the XML file directly, but I wish to do so using only Illustrator as this workflow is for non technical people.

Thanks,

/J

Comment: It constantly amazes me how opening a file in a text editor is considered too technical. (Not that I blame you – you are not overwhelmed by this.)

Comment: Well, it is what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of this article in 2013: http://schepers.cc/authoring-accessible-svg (alas, I can't find the author's name...someone please add it if they can find it!)

...Adobe Illustrator allows you to add `title` and `description` at the document level--but not object level within AI's GUI.

[image]

Inkscape allows you to add `title` and `description` to both the document itself as well as the individual elements within.

[image]